# Why is my intersection of lat lon points in R not aligning with the correct zip codes?

Tags: r, r-sf

This has been driving me nuts all day.  I am mapping lat/lon coordinates to zip codes in North Carolina.  ~5000 out of the 6000 points are mapping just fine, however, points around the military bases (Fort Bragg) were not mapping to any zip code.  I wrote code to get the nearest zip code to each point to map it to those zip codes, but when I go back to check to make sure it worked correctly, it is mapping the points to zip codes not even close to where the lat/lon coordinates are.

Here is a link to the shapefile
https://www.nconemap.gov/datasets/nconemap::zip-code-tabulation-areas/about

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

### Sample data from 3 points that did not work.

POINT_LAT = c(35.18, 35.181, 35.182)
POINT_LON = c(-79.19, -79.272, -79.24)

all_points = cbind(POINT_LAT, POINT_LON)

zipcode_nc = read.sf(NC_zipcodes.shp)
zipmap = st_transform(zipcode_nc, crs = 4326)

locations_zip = st_as_sf(all_points, coords = "POINT_LON", "POINT_LAT"), crs = st_crs(zipmap))

point_zips = locations_zip %>%
    mutate(intersection = as.integer(st_intersects(geometry, zipmap)), area = if_else(is.na(intersection), ' ', zipmap$GEOID10,[intersection]))

## Try to map missing points to closest zip code.

points_zips_external_nearest = point_zips %>%
    filter(is.na(intersection)) %>%
    st_nearest_feature(zipmap)

points_zips_external = points_zips %>%
    filter(is.na(intersection)) %>%
    mutate(zip = point_zips$ZIP[points_zips_external_nearest])
```

This gives the wrong zip codes for the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your example code caused me a couple of errors:

- Couldn't find `read.sf()` function - do you mean `read_sf()`?
- I couldn't make `locations_zip` using `st_as_sf()` without making `all_points` a tibble first.
- When making `points_zips`, specifically `mutate`ing `area` - the comma in `zipmap$GEOID10,[intersection]` isn't needed and causes an error.

As well as making sure your code is working, it would be helpful if you included the "wrong" results you are getting, and also the "right" results which you are expecting. That way other people can see if they are getting the right/wrong results themselves.

---

I simplified some of the code a bit, and I think I am getting the correct ZIP codes.

First, load libraries and data. I used `st_read()` to import the shapefile, from the name of the folder it came with when downloaded.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(tmap)

# sample points
POINT_LAT = c(35.18, 35.181, 35.182)
POINT_LON = c(-79.19, -79.272, -79.24)
all_points = cbind(POINT_LAT, POINT_LON)

# zipcode_nc = read.sf(NC_zipcodes.shp)
zipcode_nc <- st_read('ZIP_Code_Tabulation_Areas/ZIP_Code_Tabulation_Areas.shp')

zipmap = st_transform(zipcode_nc, crs = 4326)

zipmap

# Simple feature collection with 808 features and 8 fields
# Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32186 ymin: 33.84231 xmax: -75.46062 ymax: 36.58811
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# First 10 features:
#    OBJECTID ZCTA5CE10     AFFGEOID10 GEOID10   ALAND10 AWATER10   ShapeSTAre  ShapeSTLen                       geometry
# 1         1     28306 8600000US28306   28306 177888344  2457841 180219025.11 155040.4114 MULTIPOLYGON (((-79.06381 3...
# 2         2     28334 8600000US28334   28334 414866754  3998968 418736167.65 161264.1606 MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.73546 3...
# 3         3     28169 8600000US28169   28169   1450978        0   1413700.15   6504.1990 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.43786 3...
# 4         4     27278 8600000US27278   27278 262556156  2234207 264733578.27 138272.0708 MULTIPOLYGON (((-79.20634 3...
# 5         5     28325 8600000US28325   28325   2203868        0   2175834.07   7088.4067 MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.11489 3...
# 6         6     28472 8600000US28472   28472 469545124  1646985 471198707.46 225630.0920 MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.85764 3...
# 7         7     27841 8600000US27841   27841    684051        0    669653.06   4155.6886 MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.28181 3...
# 8         8     28280 8600000US28280   28280     19577        0     19572.48    560.1441 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.8442 35...
# 9         9     28560 8600000US28560   28560 304195338 65656182 314791215.62 206410.4354 MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.15578 3...
# 10       10     27881 8600000US27881   27881   1760084        0   1765449.38   8334.0644 MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.44656 3...



# locations_zip = st_as_sf(all_points, coords = c("POINT_LON", "POINT_LAT"), crs = st_crs(zipmap))
locations_zip = st_as_sf(all_points %>% as_tibble, coords = c("POINT_LON", "POINT_LAT"), crs = st_crs(zipmap))

locations_zip

# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -79.272 ymin: 35.18 xmax: -79.19 ymax: 35.182
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# # A tibble: 3 x 1
# geometry
# *      <POINT [°]>
# 1   (-79.19 35.18)
# 2 (-79.272 35.181)
# 3  (-79.24 35.182)
```

First up I tried plotting the data on a map using the `tmap` package:

```
# a map
tm_shape(zipmap)+
  tm_polygons()
# Error: Shape contains invalid polygons. Please fix it or set tmap_options(check.and.fix = TRUE) and rerun the plot
```

The error indicates some of the polygons are invalid, and be due to various reasons such as self-intersections etc. See `?st_make_valid` for more details.

So, I make the polygons valid using `st_make_valid()`, and then use `st_cast()` to separate each individual polygon. Without this some ZIP codes have multiple polygons so plotting the labels in the next step is tricky.

```
# make the polygons valid
zipmap %>% 
  st_make_valid() %>% 
  st_cast('POLYGON') %>% 
  {. ->> zipmap_2}

zipmap_2

# Simple feature collection with 966 features and 8 fields
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32186 ymin: 33.84231 xmax: -75.46062 ymax: 36.58811
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# First 10 features:
#     OBJECTID ZCTA5CE10     AFFGEOID10 GEOID10   ALAND10 AWATER10 ShapeSTAre ShapeSTLen                       geometry
# 1          1     28306 8600000US28306   28306 177888344  2457841  180219025 155040.411 POLYGON ((-79.06394 34.9998...
# 1.1        1     28306 8600000US28306   28306 177888344  2457841  180219025 155040.411 POLYGON ((-78.8688 34.89214...
# 1.2        1     28306 8600000US28306   28306 177888344  2457841  180219025 155040.411 POLYGON ((-78.86443 34.9142...
# 1.3        1     28306 8600000US28306   28306 177888344  2457841  180219025 155040.411 POLYGON ((-78.8571 34.90978...
# 1.4        1     28306 8600000US28306   28306 177888344  2457841  180219025 155040.411 POLYGON ((-79.05672 34.9803...
# 2          2     28334 8600000US28334   28334 414866754  3998968  418736168 161264.161 POLYGON ((-78.73424 35.1739...
# 3          3     28169 8600000US28169   28169   1450978        0    1413700   6504.199 POLYGON ((-81.43807 35.3547...
# 4          4     27278 8600000US27278   27278 262556156  2234207  264733578 138272.071 POLYGON ((-79.20665 35.9857...
# 5          5     28325 8600000US28325   28325   2203868        0    2175834   7088.407 POLYGON ((-78.11554 35.1526...
# 6          6     28472 8600000US28472   28472 469545124  1646985  471198707 225630.092 POLYGON ((-78.85624 34.4161...
```

Also make an `id` column for the three points, so we can plot a label on the map to see which one is which and which ZIP code is closest.

```
# make point ID for the 3 points
locations_zip %>% 
  mutate(
    id = row_number()
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> locations_zip_2}

locations_zip_2
# 
# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 1 field
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -79.272 ymin: 35.18 xmax: -79.19 ymax: 35.182
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#           geometry    id
# *      <POINT [°]> <int>
# 1   (-79.19 35.18)     1
# 2 (-79.272 35.181)     2
# 3  (-79.24 35.182)     3
```

Now we can plot a map of the ZIP codes and the three points. We include labels for each feature too. I set a `bbox` inside `tm_shape()` so it focuses on our three points, and add ZIP code labels (I assume the values in the `ZCTA5CE10` column are the ZIP codes?). I use `st_centroid()` to find the centre of each polygon, as the coordinates to place the ZIP code label.

```
# now make the map again
tmap_mode('view')

tm_shape(zipmap_2, bbox = locations_zip_2 %>% st_buffer(3000) %>% st_bbox)+
  tm_polygons()+
  tm_shape(zipmap_2 %>% st_centroid)+
  tm_text(text = 'ZCTA5CE10', size = 2)+
  tm_shape(locations_zip_2)+
  tm_dots(col = 'red')+
  tm_text(text = 'id', ymod = -3, col = 'red', size = 2)
```

[image]

Then, we use `st_nearest_feature()` to find the nearest polygon by index, and them pull out the ZIP code of the index.

```
# which is the closest zip code to each point?
locations_zip_2 %>% 
  mutate(
    nearest_index = st_nearest_feature(., zipmap_2),
    nearest_zip_code = zipmap_2$ZCTA5CE10[nearest_index]
  )

# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 3 fields
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -79.272 ymin: 35.18 xmax: -79.19 ymax: 35.182
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#           geometry    id nearest_index nearest_zip_code
# *      <POINT [°]> <int>         <int> <chr>           
# 1   (-79.19 35.18)     1            76 28315           
# 2 (-79.272 35.181)     2           117 28394           
# 3  (-79.24 35.182)     3            76 28315
```

As far as I can tell, these ZIP codes match the map so I assume they are "correct". If not, feel free to edit the question with the outputs you are getting, and what you are expecting.